# Using Javascript to add new Bootstrap Button

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML, I am trying to create conditional logic that checks if a button in a modal has been clicked, once that button has been clicked, I want to "show" a new button to the user.

My issue is the syntax creating the new button using JavaScript. I have the `onclick` attribute of the triggering button set to a new function called `addButton()` that I will place JavaScript in, but not sure syntactically how to generate a new button.

Would something like this create the button in **bootstrap format** when referenced from the `onclick` of the triggering button?:

```
<script>
        function addButton() {
            var element = document.createElement("input");
            element.type = "button";
            element.value = "View Info";
            element.name = "getInfo";
            element.className = "btn btn-info btn-lg";
        }
</script>
```

Comment: What is `getInfo`? The argument to `createElement` is the tag name, so this creates something like `<getInfo>`

Comment: You need to [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) the new element to the DOM and if you want to create a button `createElement()` should be set to tag/element you want to create.

Comment: `document.createElement("input")`

Comment: What is `element3`? Is that a typo for `element`?

Comment: Not sure what should be entered as argument for createElement to create bootstrap buttons - what should it be?

Comment: element3 is a typo

Comment: New code added to post

Comment: @colyerfs check it bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function addButton() {
     var element = document.createElement("input");
     element.type = "button";
     element.value = "View Info";
     element.name = "getInfo";
     element.className ="btn btn-info btn-lg";
     document.getElementById('button-group').appendChild(element);
 }
```

```html
<div onclick="addButton()">Click to Add new Button</div> 
<div id="button-group"><div>
```

Comment: This code shows the button, but two issues: 1. it puts the button in a crazy spot on the page, and 2. it is not triggered by the click of my other button

Comment: @colyerfs that's because you need to modify the answer to target the specific location where you want the button to append. We don't know where you want it and it's down to you to set the function call on your other button since you haven't shared or explained anyone of this "other button"

Comment: fair enough - regardless, calling the function at the end of the script doesn't depend on the click of the "other button"

Comment: @colyerfs the function call at the bottom is for the sake of the snippet so you can see the source code works.

Comment: document.body is just an example we can use by selecting the element and  
and then append.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append it to the body.

```
<script>
    function addButton() {
      var element = document.createElement("input");
      element.type = "button";
      element.value = "View Info";
      element.name = "getInfo";
      element.className = "btn btn-info btn-lg";
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(element);
    }
</script>
```